# Evaporation of Molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, atoms, kinetic-theory

In Feynman Vol. 1, I have read:

> If we blow on the water so as to maintain a continuous preponderance in the numbers evaporating, then the water is cooled.'

My question is, how does the continuous preponderance help molecules to keep evaporating?

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of preponderance is:

> 1. A superiority or excess in number or quantity
> 2. A majority

Hence, if we are able to maintain a continuous preponderance of water molecules leaving the surface over the water molecules coming in, the cooling effect of evaporation is greater. **In other words, Feynman tells us that if we blow on water, the majority of the water molecules leave the surface instead of coming back.**